# Writable nested serializers with inherited django models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to update records with the writeable nested serializers I've created.

There are many `Listing` categories for a classifieds app I'm creating that each have a few unique attributes, but they also share many attributes. I have a handful of django models that inherit from a parent `Listing` model, and one of these models, `Battery`, contains some nested data. So far I've been able to create `Battery` records but keep getting AttributeErrors when I try to update them.

I've tried to include only the relevant code. Here are my views:

```
# views.py

class ListingCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        category = self.request.data['category']
        if category == 1:
            return PercussionSerializer
         elif category == 6:
            return BatterySerializer

        return ListingSerializer

class ListingUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        category = self.request.data['category']
        if category == 1:
            return PercussionSerializer
        elif category == 6:
            return BatterySerializer

        return ListingSerializer
```

here are my models:

```
# models.py

## Parent model
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=0.00)

## One of the child models
class Battery(Listing):
    model_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacture_year = models.IntegerField(null=True)

## Model for the nested data in Battery model
class Drum(models.Model):
    drum_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    size = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    battery = models.ForeignKey(Battery, related_name='drums', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and here are my serializers:

```
# serializers.py

class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = '__all__'

class DrumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Drum
        fields = ['drum_type', 'size', 'carrier', 'stand', 'cover', 'case', 'sold']

class BatterySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    drums = DrumSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Battery
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'model_name', 'color', 'manufacture_year', 'drums']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        drum_data = validated_data.pop('drums')
        battery = Battery.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for drum_data in drum_data:
            Drum.objects.create(battery=battery, **drum_data)
        return battery

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Update Listing field values
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.price = validated_data.get('price', instance.price)
        
        # Grab the Battery record for this Listing and update its values
        instance_battery = Battery.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        instance_battery.model_name = validated_data.get('model_name', instance_battery.model_name)
        instance_battery.color = validated_data.get('color', instance_battery.color)
        instance_battery.manufacture_year = validated_data.get('manufacture_year', instance_battery.manufacture_year)

        # Check for a list of drums
        drum_data = validated_data.pop('drums')
        # If it exists
        if drum_data:
            # Clear the existing drums
            instance_battery.drums.clear()
            # Create new drums
            Drum.objects.bulk_create(
                [
                    Drum(**drum)
                    for drum in drum_data
                ],
            )

        # Save the updated Listing & Battery
        instance.save()
        instance_battery.save()
        # Return the updated Battery
        return instance
```

I feel like I've followed the DRF documentation about [writeable nested serializers correctly](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but I continue to get this AttributeError when I try to post an update to a `Battery` record:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `drums` on serializer `BatterySerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Listing` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'Listing' object has no attribute 'drums'.

Judging by the error message I think the Django model inheritance requires a more specific solution that what the DRF documentation provides. Can anybody help me understand how to create the serializers I need to create/update a `Battery` record that inherits from a `Listing` model with a nested list of `Drum` records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem appears because the view waits for a Listing instance. I can suggest the following: try to redefine `def get_qyeryset(self)`

For example:

```
class ListingUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.data['category'] == 6:
            return Battery.objects.all()
        else:
            return Listing.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        category = self.request.data['category']
        if category == 1:
            return PercussionSerializer
        elif category == 6:
            return BatterySerializer

        return ListingSerializer
```

Maybe it is not the best way, but it can solve your problem

Comment: I haven't had time to thoroughly test this solution yet, but it does seem to have fixed the problem. Once I'm able to test this completely and things seem to be working I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thanks a bunch!